# Get-ADUser properties in specific order to export into CSV

Tags: powershell, hashtable, export-to-csv

Semi-Newbie here.  I'm trying to use Get-ADUser to display user information in a specific order.  It appears Get-ADUser property listing has a default order that is not intuitive for our needs.  So far I have;

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $treeview.SelectedNode.Name -Properties Name, CN, SamAccountName, DisplayName, sn, GivenName, Initials, `
OtherName, mail, EmailAddress, EmployeeNumber, Company, StreetAddress, POBox, City, State, PostalCode, Country, Department, HomePhone, `
telephoneNumber, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, Fax, info, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, Title, Office, EmployeeID, Description, DistinguishedName, `
CanonicalName, AccountExpirationDate, Created, Enabled, HomeDirectory, HomeDrive, HomePage, LastLogonDate, LockedOut, logonCount, Manager, `
Modified, msNPAllowDialin, ObjectClass, objectSid, PasswordLastSet, UserPrincipalName, whenChanged | 
Select-Object Name, CN, SamAccountName, `
DisplayName, sn, GivenName, Initials, OtherName, mail, EmailAddress, EmployeeNumber, Company, StreetAddress, POBox, City, State, PostalCode, `
Country, Department, HomePhone, telephoneNumber, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, Fax, info, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, Title, Office, EmployeeID, `
Description, DistinguishedName, CanonicalName, AccountExpirationDate, Created, Enabled, HomeDirectory, HomeDrive, HomePage, LastLogonDate, `
LockedOut, logonCount, Manager, Modified, msNPAllowDialin, ObjectClass, objectSid, PasswordLastSet, UserPrincipalName, whenChanged `
| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $LogFile
```

Although the below code works fairly quickly (4 sec. for 1758 users), this seems a bit long winded and I'm sure there are more efficient methods.  I've looked into hash tables but even that is as long as above doubling the effort.

Comment: change your `-Properties Long, List, of, Stuff` to '-Properties *` to grab ALL the props. then build your `Select-Object` list. i would use an array to hold the property list, but that is not needed.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Only reason I don't use '-Properties *', for the little bit of 1758 users it goes from 4 seconds up to 24 seconds when using *.

Comment: ah! that makes sense. [*grin*] so ... add the props to a list, and use the list in your two locations.

Answer (score 2):

If we are to follow [Lee_Dailey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) advice, you can store the properties you want to filter into an array variable. Then pass that variable into the `-Property`/`-Properties` parameters.

```
$properties = "DisplayName","sn","GivenName","Initials","OtherName","mail","EmailAddress","EmployeeNumber","Company","StreetAddress","POBox","City","State","PostalCode","Country","Department","HomePhone","telephoneNumber","OfficePhone","MobilePhone","Fax","info","physicalDeliveryOfficeName","Title","Office","EmployeeID","Description","DistinguishedName","CanonicalName","AccountExpirationDate","Created","Enabled","HomeDirectory","HomeDrive","HomePage","LastLogonDate","LockedOut","logonCount","Manager","Modified","msNPAllowDialin","ObjectClass","objectSid","PasswordLastSet","UserPrincipalName","whenChanged"

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $treeview.SelectedNode.Name -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object -Property $properties
```

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings.  Does it make any difference if I'm reformatting on of the fields?  For example, I still my code is still listed as above in original post except after the Select-Object command, I'm reformatting the CanonicalName to remove the user name, i.e...  
  
  
`@{ Name = 'OU'; Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.Split('/')[0..($_.CanonicalName.Split('/').count - 2)] -join '/' } }`

Comment: You can have a base list with no custom properties called `$properties`. Then you can add the extra properties in your command like `get-aduser -filter * -properties ($properties + 'CanonicalName') | select $properties,@{n='OU';e={$_.CanonicalName.Split('/') # stuff}}`.

Comment: Another approach is to include the calculated properties into your variable like `$properties = 'Name','EmployeeID','CanonicalName',@{n='OU';e={$_.CanonicalName.Split('/')}}`. Then you can leave off that calculated property in your `get-aduser` command --> `get-aduser -filter * -properties $properties[0..2] | select $properties`.